# Find the limit of $S_n^{\frac{1}{n}}$, where $S_n=\frac{n^n}{(n+1)(n+2) \ldots(n+n)}$

Tags: real-analysis

Have a look at this question:

If $S_n=\frac{n^n}{(n+1)(n+2) \ldots(n+n)}$, then $\left\{\left(S_n\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}\right\}$ converges to

(1) $\frac{e}{2}$

(2) $\frac{e}{4}$

(3) $\frac{e}{8}$

(4) $0$

I have an inequality between geometric and arithmetic means as
$$0 \leq S_n^{\frac{1}{n}} \leq \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{n+k},$$ But the right hand side goes to $\ln 2$ as $n \to \infty$ and still not useful.

Thanks in advance for any appreciable help.

Comment: Hint: Take the logarithm and recognize the resulting expression as a Riemann sum.

Comment: Ya....I got it, thnks a lot.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to solve it is with Stirling's approximation, recall $n! \sim \left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n \sqrt{2\pi n}$.
Then

$$
S_n = \frac{n^n}{(n+1)(n+2)\ldots(n+n)} = \frac{n^n n!}{(2n)!} \sim \frac{n^n (\frac{n}{e})^n \sqrt{2\pi n}}{(\frac{2n}{e})^{2n}\sqrt{4 \pi n}}
$$
and so

$$
S_n^{\frac{1}{n}} \sim \frac{n (\frac{n}{e}) (2\pi n)^{\frac{1}{n}} }{ (\frac{2n}{e})^2 (4\pi n)^{\frac{1}{n}} } = \frac{ n^2 e^2 }{ 4n^2 e 2^{\frac{1}{n}} } = \frac{e}{4 \cdot 2^{\frac{1}{n}}} \to \frac{e}{4}. 
$$

Answer (score 3):

Hint: You can apply the limit test on $S_{n}$. It is a positive sequence. The limit $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{S_{n+1}}{S_{n}}$ exists, and therefore, you can take this limit, which is equal to the limit $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}{S_{n}}^{\frac{1}{n}}$ .